# OBD request trouble code mode 3 and mode 7

Tags: obd-ii, electronic-control-module, dtc

I'm trying to get my own app on phone to read Trouble code in car...
I see that i have 3 mode to do this... first is to use the mode 01 with command 01 (but this command is generic) or the mode 03 and 07.

From documentation of the [ELM Eletronics](https://www.elmelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ELM327DS.pdf)
they use mode 0101 and after mode 03 for getting trouble code.

But i read that the mode 07 give trouble code too, but in my case i disconnect a cable of my car and with command 03 i receive the error P0105 but with command 07 i receive two trouble code... P0105 and P0110.

So which is the best between mode 03 and mode 07...they are different?

Comment: Mode 3 returns hard fault DTCs, meaning single trip codes or two trip codes that have failed twice. Mode 7 returns pending DTCs, meaning two trip codes that have failed only once.

Comment: So it's better mode 07? because if one trouble code was appeared not mean that it can be auto-solved.
Or not?

Comment: Neither is better. They are tools that do different things. Mode 3 can have codes that Mode 7 does not and vice versa. Think of it like a knife and axe. They both cut, but different things. I'm also not sure what you mean by "auto-solved"?

Comment: if i understand what you say mode 3 show trouble code that are permanent so the trouble code that appear every time that car is take on.
Mode 7 show trouble code that appear only one time (so errors that appear not always)....right?

Comment: Mode 3, yes exactly. Mode 7 not quite. A pending code is one that requires the failure to show up twice. The Mode 7 code is set after the failure has shown up once. If it shows up again it will become a Mode 3 code. If it never shows up again it will eventually disappear.

Comment: so, in my application if use mode 7 it's enough because i read all possible trouble of car!

Comment: It is a good idea to check both. If the check engine light is not on, then checking 7 only works.

Comment: i'm trying with my car by disconnecting one cable of intake air pressure and with command 04 i see only one error but with 07 see same error plus another one more.
P0105(all two) P0110(only 07).... and this problem is always there, why mode 04 don't detect it?

And my MIL light is on.

Comment: P0105 is a hard fault. P0110 is pending and will eventually become a hard fault. Please read up on the difference between a hard fault and a pending code.